# How to create histogram output using neo4j Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With `create_time` and `delete_time` attributes in our graph model entities, is there an efficient way to create queries that will return the counts, similar to a histogram, indicating in which time bins the entities "existed"?  The time bins will also be a variable.  For example, per year for the last 10 years, or per month for the past 36 months, or per day for the past 30 days.  The times are stored in integer format (but this can be changed if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get the number of `Entity` nodes whose `create_time` values fall within the last N M-day windows:

```
WITH timestamp() AS now
MATCH (e:Entity)
WHERE e.create_time > now - ($nPeriods * $periodMillis)
RETURN (now - e.create_time)/$periodMillis AS period, COUNT(*) AS cnt
ORDER BY period
```

The query assumes that you pass `M` and `N` via the `periodMillis` and `nPeriods` [query parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). For example, if you want each period to be 30 days, and to see the counts for the last 5 periods, you can can pass `30*24*60*60*1000` as `periodMillis` and 5 as `nPeriods`.

To speed up this query, you should also create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Entity(create_time)`.

Here is a sample result (using the above sample numbers):

```
╒════════╤═════╕
│"period"│"cnt"│
╞════════╪═════╡
│0       │22   │
├────────┼─────┤
│1       │20   │
├────────┼─────┤
│2       │101  │
├────────┼─────┤
│3       │62   │
├────────┼─────┤
│4       │44   │
└────────┴─────┘
```

Period 0 is for the last 30 days (the period ends "now", not at midnight), period 1 is for the 30 days before that, and so forth. *Using midnight as the boundary is more complicated and would probably require you to specify a timezone and use temporal functions (like [these](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/)).*

[UPDATE]

If your period is a month, you can use the neo4j [temporal values and functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal) to perform calculations that respect the actual number of days in a month.

For example, if the parameter `nMonths` provides the maximum number of monthly periods:

```
WITH date() AS today
MATCH (e:Entity)
WITH duration.inMonths(e.create_time, today).months AS period
WHERE period < $nMonths
RETURN period, COUNT(*) AS cnt
ORDER BY period
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.  This is "close" to what is needed but will be off the mark due to the different "period" intervals needed.  For example, we need the bins to represent the last 36 months and the number of days in a month is not a constant here.  I am looking at using the neo4j Date object here instead of using an integer to represent the date/time to see if the operations on the Date object can be used.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks @cybersam - this will be most useful!